# Angular-translate Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im using angular translate in my app, this is my app.js

```
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'pascalprecht.translate'
]).config(function($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
       HEADLINE: 'Hello there, This is my awesome app!',
       INTRO_TEXT: 'And it has i18n support!'
    });
});
```

Im fallowing tutorial I fond on the internet.

This is how I loaded libraries in my html file

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
```

And this is how i print values

```
<h2>{{ 'HEADLINE' | translate }}</h2>
<p>{{ 'INTRO_TEXT' | translate }}</p>
```

But when i open my app im getting this msg in console :

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: translateFilterProvider <- translateFilter
```

Does anyone knows how to fix this? Im absolute beginner in angular, sorry if error is stupid :)

Comment: I've edited my answer, try it like that.

Comment: Could you add a plunker or something, so I can see a running sample?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you need to add $translate as a dependency.

```
formApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $translate) {
 //code
});
```

So for example in the html, you must have a ng-controller at some point before those elements, thats the controller that needs the dependency injected as a parameter.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  ...
  <h2 translate>HEADLINE</h2>
  <p translate>INTRO_TEXT</p>
  ...
</div>
```

Also in the config block you need to set the prefered language:

```
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
```

Comment: this is how my controllers.js file is looking right now, where to add this code ? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/770ae8d72ac05aac83da

Comment: You need to add it as a dependency in the controller that is defined in the html.

Comment: Thanks ! Now i dont get error anymore, but in my html i only get this printed out HEADLINE INTRO_TEXT, I didnt get valued of it, do you know what i missed?

Comment: Should I have something in that controller or it can be empty ? Because I still donnt get values back and I dont get any errors :/

Comment: Have you added that line in the config? $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

You don't need to have anything in the controller.